# Ensuring that a SIGINT does not prevent following commands from executing

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I know it's possible to use `cmd1;cmd2;cmd3` to execute commads sequentialy, but in the case the first command is executing and it receives a SIGINT, the other commands do not execute. For Example:

```
sleep 100;echo "Finished execution"
```

If I send a `kill -9` to the sleep command pid, the echo is still executed. If I send a `kill -INT` to the sleep command pid, the second command is not executed.

My question is: is there a way to make sure the second command is going to be executed, even in the case the first process is killed by `SIGINT` signal.

Comment: One option would be to set up a [`trap`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command) to manually handle `SIGINT`

Comment: `( trap 'echo "Finished execution"' EXIT; sleep 100; )` will execute the trap, no matter which way the (sub)shell exits, e.g. after a `SIGINT`. You can `trap` on `INT` or other signals specifically (to do something special in those cases), except `KILL` and `STOP`, of course. There are also non-signal events you can `trap`, like `EXIT` and `RETURN` in case of functions.

Comment: Actually, this example does not reproduce for me. `( sleep 100;echo "Finished execution" ) &` and afterwards `killall -INT sleep` produced the expected output.

Comment: @user3840170 because you executed the commands between parenthisis! That's the answer. If I execute (cmd1;cmd2;cmd3) it creates a subshell for each, so the SIGINT kills only the command that received it, not the whole sequence.

Comment: You did not mention this being in an interactive shell, so I used a backgrounded subshell when testing to simulate a stand-alone script (where it behaves the same). You should probably edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: Interactive shells have this behavior with job control enabled. Shell scripts and interactive shells with job control disabled generally won't have a problem continuing after an executed command receives SIGINT. Basically this behavior exists so you can press e.g. CTRL+C and regain control of your interactive shell even if you have commands "queued" versus having to mash the keys over and over.

Answer (score 2):

First, [don't use `kill -9`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...) as if that's just how you spell it.
[kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) sends any of several signals, but if you don't tell it which if defaults to 15, which is `TERM`. That's usually best. If you're trying to kill a scary bug, don't start with a sledgehammer.
(Maybe have a little courage and put it outside. ;o)

Aside from that -

Freeman's `trap` is an elegant solution that allows some nice perqs - for example, you can set traps on different signals that do different things. Andrej Podzimek's `trap`-in-a-subshell as presented in a comment is kind of beautiful. Depending on your tastes and level of competence, `trap` might be overkill, but I always recommend taking the time to learn the use and value of something new.

If you wanted the second command to ONLY execute if the first finished, use a basic conditional. Let's look at an easily understood example first:

```
$: if sleep 10; then echo ok; fi & # output shows up after another
[1] 487
$: ok

[1]+  Done                    if sleep 10; then
    echo ok;
fi
```

I ran a simple `if` statement in background. It finished, output as asked (which showed up after my next prompt, don't let that confuse you, I didn't type the "ok", I just hit the RETURN there to get the next prompt, which showed me the background job had finished.)

If I add a command to then kill the process I just ran in bg:

```
$: if sleep 10; then echo ok; fi & kill $!
[1] 498
[1]+  Terminated              if sleep 10; then
    echo ok;
fi
```

It immediately terminates with no output, because the `if` didn't get a valid success completion return code of zero from the `sleep`.

You can achieve a similar result with the more compact double-ampersand syntax. (Lots of other toys available - great cheat sheet [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet).)

```
$: sleep 10 && echo ok & 
[1] 502
$: ok

[1]+  Done                    sleep 10 && echo ok

$: sleep 10 && echo ok & kill $!
[1] 510
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 10 && echo ok
```

---

But in your case, you want the second command to execute even if the `sleep` is interrupted. I don't see any special effort needed for *that*, except to make sure the second command is NOT conditional on the first.

```
$: ( date; sleep 999; date ) &
[1] 569
Thu Aug 31 11:37:57 CDT 2023
$: ps | grep -E '[/]sleep|PID'
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
      574     569     569      15568  pty0     2136995 11:37:57 /usr/bin/sleep
$: kill -INT 574
Thu Aug 31 11:38:21 CDT 2023
[1]+  Done                    ( date; sleep 999; date )
```

Maybe I'm missing some detail still?
I obviously misread your intent initially.
Hope this helps more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul, but my question is more related to how to create a shell script that runs the commands sequentially even when a SIGINT is sent to one of the commands, I don't think there is a way to achieve that by using conditionals.

Comment: But readying the reference you provided, I have found a answer to my question.

Comment: Updated - sorry for the misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trap` in combination with a signal handler to catch the `SIGINT` signal and execute the second command before exiting,and as you see below the `handle_sigint` function is executed when the script receives the `SIGINT` signal :

```
#!/bin/bash

#to handle SIGINT
handle_sigint() {
    echo "SIGINT signal received"
    echo "Executing second command..."
    #here, you can adding your second command
    echo "Second command executed"
    exit 0
}

#registering the signal handler
trap handle_sigint SIGINT

#first command
sleep 100

#second command
echo "Finished execution"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the behaviour is due to Job Control, try this :

```
set +m # Disable Job Control
sleep 100;echo "Finished execution"
set -m
```